# Is it possible to use HTTPS without a website host like GoDaddy?

Tags: web-applications, https, web-deployment

I am planning to begin building a web app and still working out the details, but I am relatively new to web development, and unsure about HTTPS. I'll implement a login system, among other features which will need HTTPS, and I wanted to begin by hosting this myself and testing on my home network before seeing about getting it on AWS or something.
A few unsuccessful google searches have left me still thinking, if this is possible, what technologies/frameworks do I use to establish an HTTPS connection between client and server on a local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get free SSL/TLS certs from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). IMO it's pretty easy to setup though you need to have a domain. In a production setting on AWS, you'd want to use [NGINX](https://nginx.org/en/) or Apache as a reverse proxy for your application and terminate your SSL there but for your local dev any of the standard web frameworks ([Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/), [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), etc) will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily test this out on local or home machine instead of buying a domain and hosting on AWS for experimental purposes.

You can install apache server for HTTPS requests. You could then use any back end scripting language to build you application.

You would get apache server, php, mysql in LAMP stack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle). Try seaching how to install LAMP stack in linux or XAMP in windows.